# How to fix an unknown IP getting in the way of accessing Hive using Spark?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am trying to access hive tables using pyspark. However, I am facing issue with gateway: some unresolved host with a public IP of an ec2 instance.

I have port-forwarded hive to my localhost 9083 and 10000 ports(metastore and hive db) using the command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_sc -L 9000:<Presto server>:8080 -L 10000:hive_server:10000 -L 9083:hive_server:9083 ubuntu@bayseian_node
```

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, HiveContext
SparkContext.setSystemProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
sparkSession = (SparkSession
                .builder
                .appName('example-pyspark-read-and-write-from-hive')
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate())
data = [('First', 1), ('Second', 2), ('Third', 3), ('Fourth', 4), ('Fifth', 5)]
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data)
# Write into Hive
df.write.saveAsTable('example')
```

The expected result would be an acknowledgment that the table has been saved. Although, the actual ones are:

```
2019-03-26 15:59:13 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.0/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/aviralsrivastava/.virtualenvs/spark/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.saveAsTable.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-172-16-1-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.validateTableLocation(SessionCatalog.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.createTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:400)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-172-16-1-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal
    ... 45 more


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gh_eg.py", line 12, in <module>
    df.write.saveAsTable('example')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.0/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 775, in saveAsTable
    self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)
  File "/Users/aviralsrivastava/.virtualenvs/spark/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.0/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-172-16-1-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, HiveContext
"""
SparkSession ss = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName(" Hive example")
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate();
"""

sparkSession = (SparkSession
                .builder
                .appName('example-pyspark-read-and-write-from-hive')
                .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083", conf=SparkConf())
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate()
                )
data = [('First', 1), ('Second', 2), ('Third', 3), ('Fourth', 4), ('Fifth', 5)]
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data)
# Write into Hive
#df.write.saveAsTable('example')

df_load = sparkSession.sql('SELECT * FROM example')
df_load.show()
print(df_load.show())
```

As you can see, the change is **conf=SparkConf()** in the `config` attribute of `SparkSession`.

After this change, I could get the expected results.